# Unable to Run MPI CLUSTER within a LAN

Tags: ssh, mpi, mpich

This is the sanpshot of my **/etc/hosts** file

[image]

karpathy is master & client is slave

**I have successfully done**

> 1. SETUP PASSWORDLESS SSH
> 2. Mounted `sudo mount -t nfs karpathy:/home/mpiuser/cloud ~/cloud`

I can login to my client simply by `ssh client`

I have followed this blog 
http://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/running-an-mpi-cluster-within-a-lan/

`mpirun -np 5 -hosts karpathy ./cpi` output

[image]

`mpirun -np 5 -hosts client ./cpi`

**Getting Error**

`[mpiexec@karpathy] HYDT_dmxu_poll_wait_for_event (./tools/demux/demux_poll.c:77): callback returned error status
[mpiexec@karpathy] HYD_pmci_wait_for_completion (./pm/pmiserv/pmiserv_pmci.c:179): error waiting for event
[mpiexec@karpathy] main (./ui/mpich/mpiexec.c:397): process manager error waiting for completion`

Comment: Maybe `mpirun -nolocal`?

Comment: I want to run on client remote host

Comment: ... and therefore not the local one...

Comment: Check if there is a firewall enabled on both the master and client nodes. If there is, disable it and try your experiment again.

Comment: Try trouble shooting by    `ssh client ./cpi`   . If that does not work, there is a problem with ssh, telnet, path-filename or permission.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you already have found the solution, in case you haven't I would suggest doing a couple of things.
1. disabling firewall on both the nodes by doing `

> **sudo ufw disable**

`
2. Creating a file named as machinefile (or whatever u like) and storing the number of CPU's in both nodes along with the hostnames. 
my machinefile contains:

> `master:8 
>   slave:4`

master and slave are the hostnames while 8 and 4 are the number of CPUs on each node.

3. to compile use

> mpicc -o filename filename.cpp

4. to run use the machinefile as an argument

> mpirun -np 12 -f machinefile ./filename

12 is th enumber of processes. Since both the nodes have 12 CPUs combined so it's better to divide the code on 12 processes.